# How to save image after edit in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

I want to save the rotated image to the photo library. I have a UIImageView in which the image is displayed. I used the below snippet to flip the image. The rotated image does get displayed since I transform the image view. But while saving the image I get the original image (not flipped). How do I save a flipped image?

```
CGAffineTransform transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees));
   image.transform = transform;
```

Comment: Hello Shanmu, Are you get the solution for this issue? I have the same problem, Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Simply take a screenshot of the image or the view in which it is saved and it would be saved as it is whether it has been rotated or flipped.... Here is some code provided....

```
-(IBAction)saveToPhotoGallery:(id)sender
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(baseView.frame.size);
    [baseView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *attachimage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:Data];
    UIImage *viImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    attachimage = viImage;
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viImage, nil, nil, nil);

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" message:@"Saved to photo gallery" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: only original image is saved to photo library not a rotated image